# What can I add to a dough ( kind of pizza dough) to keep it fresh after frozen?

Tags: food-chemistry

I make some "mini pizzas" with a dough recipe i learned in Brasil, I'm interested in freezing the dough after being "half baked" meaning baked for half of the time, so I can bake again after frozen. I was wondering if there is something I can add that will make this dough taste more fresh even after frozen

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better asked on Cooking.SE.